# RegEx Format For Specific Number

Tags: regex, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to validate TextFields in compose using Regex, and have hit a wall.
I need the input to be as follows (0's are digits 0-9, 9 is explicitly 9):
`0.009`

For reference:

- "1.359" should pass
- "1.355" should not pass
- "1.35" should not pass
- "1" should not pass
  "1." should not pass

I want it to be filled out in a way that asks the user to input DIGIT, then ".", then DIGIT, then DIGIT, then "9".

Here is my current attempt:

```
val re = remember { Regex("(^[0-9]{1})[.]([0-9]{2})?(9)?") }

OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.width(180.dp),
    value = price,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(re)) {
        priceChanged(it) }
                    },
```

What I get when applied to the app is a text field that won't allow me to input any digits or a decimal point to meet said condition because it doesn't fit the format lined up.

Comment: Are you validating the format while the user is typing? You have to wait until they've finished entering the number before validating, because partial input won't match.

Comment: Currently my code is validating with every input

Comment: Can you provide some example input that should pass and some that shouldn't? How many digits are allowed before the decimal point? How many are allowed after? Is the 9 at the end optional or mandatory? And do you need the matches of the regex? You do use parentheses, though you say you just want to check *if* it matches, not the matches itself.

Comment: Try `^(?:[0-9](?:[.](?:[0-9](?:[0-9]9?)?)?)?)?$`

Comment: @Leviathan The first paragraph describes the format. 1 digit, decimal point, 2 digits, 9.

Comment: The regexp has `?` after `([0-9]{2})` and `(9)`. That makes them optional, but you said they're required.

Comment: @Barmer: I know, but I doubt that that actually is what the op wanted, hence the request for clarification. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
val re = remember { Regex("^(?:[0-9](?:[.](?:[0-9](?:[0-9]9?)?)?)?)?$") }
```

The purpose of the expression is to match any following symbol if the previous symbol is an allowed one.

So, the first is any digit, then a `.` should come, then any digit, again any digit and then a `9` digit.

You can [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/2YkPQp/1).